# Fractional Assignation

Tags: r, statistics

Suppose I have the dataset

| ID | Country | Count | fraction | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Austria | 10 | 0.33 | A |
| 1 | Belgium | 10 | 0.66 | B |
| 1 | Belgium | 10 | 0.66 | B |
| 2 | Czech | 15 | 0.25 | C |
| 2 | Denmark | 15 | 0.75 | C |
| 2 | Denmark | 15 | 0.75 | D |
| 2 | Denmark | 15 | 0.75 | D |

So the above 'fraction' variable is due to the number of countries in each ID.

I want to decompose this even further by depending on their type.
So for each ID, it should have (#Countries)*(#Types) row.
For example

| ID | Country | Count | fraction | Type | newfraction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Austria | 10 | 0.33 | A | 0.33*0.5 |
| 1 | Austria | 10 | 0.33 | B | 0.33*0.5 |
| 1 | Belgium | 10 | 0.66 | A | 0.66*0.5 |
| 1 | Belgium | 10 | 0.66 | B | 0.66*0.5 |
| 2 | Czech | 15 | 0.25 | C | 0.25*0.50 |
| 2 | Czech | 15 | 0.75 | D | 0.25*0.5 |
| 2 | Denmark | 15 | 0.75 | C | 0.75*0.5 |
| 2 | Denmark | 15 | 0.75 | D | 0.75*0.5 |

So the first row, last column we have: 0.33*0.5. This is because there was one Austria in the ID 1 out of three countries (for the first 0.33), and one A out of two possible types in that ID (for 0.5)

Note its not necessary to change the Type in the second table, but I showed it for ease of understanding

This dataset is driving me nuts: thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this may help you

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
  Country = c("Austria", "Austria", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
              "Czech", "Czech", "Denmark", "Denmark"), 
  Count = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), 
  fraction = c(0.33, 0.33, 0.66, 0.66, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75), 
  Type = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "D", "C", "D"))

df <- df |> group_by(ID, Country) |> 
  mutate(newfraction = fraction / length(unique(Type)))
df
#> # A tibble: 8 × 6
#> # Groups:   ID, Country [4]
#>      ID Country Count fraction Type  newfraction
#>   <int> <chr>   <int>    <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1     1 Austria    10     0.33 A           0.165
#> 2     1 Austria    10     0.33 B           0.165
#> 3     1 Belgium    10     0.66 A           0.33 
#> 4     1 Belgium    10     0.66 B           0.33 
#> 5     2 Czech      15     0.25 C           0.125
#> 6     2 Czech      15     0.75 D           0.375
#> 7     2 Denmark    15     0.75 C           0.375
#> 8     2 Denmark    15     0.75 D           0.375
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This does not begin with the initial dataset. Why?

Comment: Guess the first ds was solely for explanation of the problem

Comment: But OP clearly stated that *Suppose I have the dataset*.. meaning thats the ds they have and not just for expalanation